# Bash Comparing time using date

Tags: bash, date

I have a script that runs in the background and has a bunch of loops in it that check stuff and do things based on those checks. As it's right now I have a big main loop that runs every 60 seconds and smaller loops that constantly do a set of commands, sleep for an interval and then loop again.
The Interval variable is in seconds, but that could be changed to minutes or hours.

The code as it's now:

```
Small_Loop () {
    while :; do
        do things
        sleep $Interval
    done
}
Main_Loop () {
    while :; do
        test stuff and call functions based on those tests
        sleep 60
    done
}
```

All the small loops get called with a "&" after them and lastly the Main loop gets called normally.
As this is really ugly and resource heavy, how could I do this using date comparisons?

It would get the time in military format, 12:00, add the interval to that, (so if the interval is one hour it would be 13:00) and the Main_Loop could simply compare those while it loops until it needs to do something.

Something like this:

```
Update_Interval () {
    #get the new interval in **:** format
}

Main_Loop () {
    while :; do
        if [ "`date +%R`" = "$Interval" ]; then
            #do the Small_Loop's job
        fi
        Update_Interval
    done
}
```

So I guess the real question is: How to run a block of command every set interval using date comparisons.

I found out that I could use watch, but can that be used inside a script without it interfering with stuff?

Comment: Just use `cron` instead? Unless you need "script runtime" + interval as opposed to just interval spacing.

Comment: Why not use cron?  Have cron execute your script on the required intervals.

Comment: I'm not sure if cron is available on all android devices and thus can't use it, but thanks for the suggestion anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use "+%R" as simply using "+%s" would be significantly simpler.

```
prevtime=`date +%s`
currtime=0

#Interval in which the block is executed
interval=5

#The block to execute
function block() {
    echo -e "\a" #plays a beep noise
}

function main() {
    clear
    echo "Running..."
    sleep 0.1

    currtime=`date +%s`
    if [ $currtime -eq $((prevtime+interval)) ]; then
        block
        prevtime=$currtime
    fi
}

while :; do main; done
```

The command "date +%s" returns the amount of "seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC". This means your number will always be in seconds and the change in time will always be a positive number towards the future and a negative number towards the past. So all you really need to do is check how much the number has changed. If it has changed by 5, you know 5 seconds have passed.

If you want more precise timing, you can also figure out how many nano seconds have past rather than seconds using "+%s%N".

You don't have to run any background processes just as long as the block of code can execute within the interval time. If the interval time is, in your case, 60 seconds, and the block of code takes 65 seconds to execute, then it will not execute the block of code for the next interval.

As others have pointed out, you can also use [cron](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out for me! The interval can vary from few hours to few days, so this actually is even more convenient than the original method I had in mind.
The idea is that this script does multiple things simultaneously, so the code block always gets executed in the background.